# How to check if more than one value is null at the same time SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I want to add a constraint that checks if three columns are null at the same time in SQL Server.

I wrote this:

```
ALTER TABLE Measures
ADD CHECK (Temperature <> NULL AND Humidity <> NULL AND Airpressure <> NULL);
```

but it is failing. Any help?

Comment: update your question with tag (Which RDBMS you are using) and what error you are getting?

Comment: What exactly do you want: *more than one value is null at the same time* is not the same as *three columns are null at the same time*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `<>` for `NULL`.  You use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE Measures ADD CHECK (Temperature IS NOT NULL OR Humidity IS NOT NULL OR Airpressure IS NOT NULL);
```

Normally, I would just answer this in a comment.  But there are two important points to be made.  First, you want at least one of the columns to be `NOT NULL`, so `OR` is the appropriate logic, not `AND`.

Second, check constraints differ from `WHERE` conditions and `WHEN` conditions.  For the latter, a `NULL` value is treated as "false".  For `CHECK` constraints, a `NULL` value is treated as "valid" -- the constraint passes.  I'm not sure why, but your expression will always return `NULL`, so it will always pass.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use coalesce eg:

```
COALESCE (Temperature, Humidity, Airpressure) IS NOT NULL
```